# Change color on all element using a css class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to change color in all elements in class, but I have an error:

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

I have code:

```
<div class="kolorek" onclick="changeColor('34495e');" style="background-color:#34495e;"></div>
```

---

```
function changeColor(color) {
    var block = document.getElementsByClassName('kafelek');
    with (block.style) {
        backgroundColor = "#" + color;
    }
};
```

Comment: `div class="kolorek"` and `document.getElementsByClassName('kafelek')`

Comment: There's no `.style` property on a `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: _Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Contra" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details._ Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `getElementsByClassName` will return `HTMLCollection`, you have to loop through them to set the color as below.

```js
function changeColor(color) {
        var block = document.getElementsByClassName('kafelek');
        for (var i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
            block[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + color;
        }
    };
```

```html
<div class="kolorek" onclick="changeColor('34495e');" style="background-color:#34495e;">Clickable Div</div>

<div class="kafelek">Another Div</div>
```

**Note**: Instead of inline `onclick` event, you can use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: The `event` object isn't available globally in all browsers. If you add a parameter to the function, and pass the full word `event` in the attribute call, it'll work.

Comment: And it would also only change the clicked elements background-color, but the question asks for changing the background color for all elements with the given class

Comment: @Aristov You can accept the answer if it works for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are searching for the wrong element and you can access style by using element.style and to change backgroundColor it should be element.style.backgroundColor=color

check this snippet

```js
function changeColor(color) {
  var block = document.querySelector('.kolorek');
  console.log(block.style);
  block.style.backgroundColor = "#"+color;
};
```

```html
<div class="kolorek" onclick="changeColor('999999');" style="background-color:#34495e;">sdfdsfds</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The OP doesn't necessarily want to change the element being clicked, and made reference to changing all of them, so looping is implied.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using `with` is not recommended and even forbidden since es5 in strict mode (See the link I posted in the comment above). Secondly you are targeting elements with `kafelek` as their class, but the class you are showing in your html is `kolorek`. The third error is that you are trying to set a property on a HTMLCollection, but that doesn't exist. It exists on a single element. You need to refactor your code to the following:

```
function changeColor(color) {
    var block = document.getElementsByClassName('kolorek');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(block, function(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#' + color;
    }
};
```